# Assert element not exist without exception

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to make an if statement so I can use my code in multiple situations.

When i try to assert displayed or enable I get in some situations an exception Iwebelement could not be found.

I want to make a statement that if element exist 'x' should happen and when element does not exist 'y' should happen.

As mentioned I tried Displayed, Enabled. I also tried asserFalse but that also didnt gave me the required result.

It was asked for code but I only need a if statement that let something true if element exist otherwise should skip it. When I do

```
if (element.Displayed)
{
}
```

But in some cases I get an exception and I dont want the exception

Comment: Add some code to illustrate maybe ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if Element exists in c# Selenium drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516545/how-to-check-if-element-exists-in-c-sharp-selenium-drivers)

Comment: @JacobKrall On that webpage they use IsElementPresent I assume that in c# that is GetAttribute because I dont have the option for IsElementPresent

Comment: `IsElementPresent` is a function they wrote themselves. the source code for it is in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for multiple elements and even if one exists (>0), then return true, otherwise, non of the elements with a specific `By` exist.

```
bool ElementExists()
{
    return driver.FindElements(By.Id("your locator")).Count > 0;
}
```

Then just do

```
bool ElementExists(By locator)
{
    TimeSpan originalWait = driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait;
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);

    bool exists = driver.FindElements(locator).Count > 0;

    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = originalWait;

    return exists;
}

if(ElementExists(By.Id("your locator")))
{
    //Do Stuff
}
else
{
    //Do Stuff when element does not exist
}
```

Edit: Also reduce your implicit wait to 0 seconds so you don't wait long for your bool to return (the webdriver will wait for the element to appear as long as you told).

Answer (score 1):

is this in a TestNG or JUnit test?

I would usually handle this in a normal case inside the if statement:

pseudocode:

```
if(exists(x)){
     assertTrue(....);
}
else{
    assertFalse(....);
}
```

Comment: I dont understand this. exists is that displayed ? If so then I get exception, I am using the NUnit Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will work only when the element is displayed or exists , if not it will throw the exception and you are not handling that, so the script is failing for you.

You can create a method like below by handling the exception(I have written it in java , please make the required changes).

```
public static Boolean isElementDisplayed(WebDriver driver, By element) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(element).isDisplayed();
            System.out.println("Element is displayed");
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException | ElementNotVisibleException e) {
            System.out.println("Element not displayed");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And you can use the above method in you test cases 'n' number times like this.

```
if(isElementDisplayed(driver, By.xpath("locator")){
            //do what you have to do if element is exists
        }else{
          //do what you have to do if element is not exists
        }
```

Hope this will solve your problem