# Selenium C# how to check a disabled element is displayed

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I am checking if an element is displayed.  My assertion was returning false and I found out it is because the element is disabled.
I would like to check if the element is displayed whether it is enabled or disabled.

My code snippet is (from our framework the method to check if element is displayed):

```
public bool IsElementPresent(IWebDriver browser, IWebElement element)
        {
            return utility.Element.IsDisplayed(element).Invoke(browser);
        }


public Func<IWebDriver, bool> IsDisplayed(IWebElement element)
        {
            return driver =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return element.Displayed;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageHandler.OutputError(e);
                    return false;
                }
            };
        }
```

Code snippet of the method which calls IsElementPresent:

```
public void CheckSportsLoginDialogIsDisplayed()
        {
            Actions.Verify.IsElementPresent(Browser, SportsLogin).Should().BeTrue();
       }
```

The locator:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "input.loginButton.submitButton.loginSubmit")]
private IWebElement SportsLogin { get; set; }
```

The HTML element:

```
<input class="loginButton submitButton loginSubmit disabled" value="Log in" type="submit" disabled="">
```

How do I check this element is present?  It does not matter if it is disabled or enabled.
Thanks, 
Riaz

Comment: I just did a quick test with `<input type="text" id="name" readonly>` so that it's readonly and then used `Driver.FindElement(By.Id("name")).Displayed` and it returned `true`. I think something else is going on here. I know that when Selenium checks for if something is clickable, it checks for displayed and enabled which would imply that something that is *disabled* should still return `true` for displayed. Are you sure your locator is pointing to the right `INPUT`? Are you sure that the element is actually visible when you are testing it? Have you tried adding a wait first?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer now.  The element was in an iFrame.  The IFrame was further up in the HTML tree.  I had to switch to it and then check the element is displayed.  My code is now working.

```
<iframe name="freebet" id="freebet" src="https://sports.companya.com/freebet" scrolling="auto" style="display: inline; height: 465px;" class="freebet" cd_frame_id_="9c810a320feffc91ad5fde8519f4d0cb"></iframe>

public void CheckSportsLoginDialogIsDisplayed()
    {
        Actions.Navigate.ToFrame(Browser,FrameOption.Default);                        
        Actions.Verify.IsElementPresent(Browser, SportsLogin).Should().BeTrue();            
    }
```

Comment: That's the problem with `catch (Exception e)`... you catch more than you intend and hide unexpected errors.

Comment: As stated by JeffC above, ideally you catch what you need to catch, especially when debugging. In this case since you're checking for visibility, catch: `ElementNotVisibleException` as shown on SeleniumHQ [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotVisibleException.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
if(SportsLogin != null) // should be null if not present 
{
    bool isDisplayed = SportsLogin.Displayed;
}
```

Or create an Extension

```
/// <summary>
/// Requires finding element by FindElementSafe(By).
/// Returns T/F depending on if element is defined or null.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="element">Current element</param>
/// <returns>Returns T/F depending on if element is defined or null.</returns>
public static bool Exists(this IWebElement element)
{
    if (element == null)
    { return false; }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
bool exists = SportsLogin.Exist();
```

Comment: Elements aren't `null` if they aren't present. They throw exceptions when they aren't found before they can ever become `null.`

Comment: @JeffC  Ahh noted, they throw `NoSuchElementFoundException` thanks

Comment: If I try the 1st method mentioned before the Extension suggestion I get the error Exception thrown: 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' in WebDriver.Support.dll

Comment: The Login element is displayed on the screen.  It is disabled.  My concern is to check the element is displayed on the screen whether it is disabled or enabled.  Thanks

Comment: Because the element is in a disabled state Selenium does not assert to true when checking if the element is displayed.  How do I check a disabled element is displayed please?

Comment: @RiazLadhani does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516545/how-to-check-if-element-exists-in-c-sharp-selenium-drivers/27516643) answer help