# Selenium error: no such element: Unable to locate element on .isDisplayed() method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an if statement below which is getting me an issue.  If certain selections are made in a different dropdown, the page displays a second dropdown and a check box. The below code works as expected when a selection is made that causes those two elements to display but it doesn't if a selection is made that doesn't make them display. I get the `no such element: Unable to locate element` error. At first I thought it was returning true either way but the issue is it's crashing because. I even added a check at trying to assign the value to a booolean but still get the same error.

`boolean dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("DROPDOWN")).isDisplayed();` gets the same error.

```
      if(driver.findElement(By.id("DROPDOWN")).isDisplayed()){

                driver.findElement(By.id("DROPDOWN")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("Choice in Drop DOWN)).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("CheckBox")).click();  
     }
```

Comment: what does a webdriverwait condition look like? I had thought about that but wasn't sure how to work it out

Comment: I think ".isDisplayed()" will check a style attribute, but if the element does not exist it's going to throw no such element before calling the method.  You should use a webdriverwait with findElements.  It will return an empty array if it does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

findElement method will throw this hard exception - No such element if the element is not found. Just include Exception Handling for No Such Element and your logic should work just fine.

```
try{
if(driver.findElement(By.id("DROPDOWN")).isDisplayed()){

                driver.findElement(By.id("DROPDOWN")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("Choice in Drop DOWN)).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("CheckBox")).click();  
     }
catch (NoSuchElementException e)
{
// I believe you dont have to do anything here. May be a console log will do.
}
```

Comment: This does work but seems like an odd solution. I don't understand how the method only returns true and rather than returning false, it throws an exception. The document says it's a boolean. https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html

Comment: findElement method is getting executed before isDisplayed method is executed. Hence the error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The following answers explain how to handle checking an element exists and handle the exception by wrapping in a custom method.

[How to check if Element exists in c# Selenium drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516545/how-to-check-if-element-exists-in-c-sharp-selenium-drivers)

I would also recommend re-writing your code as the following to avoid duplication and avoid xpath selectors. Using findElement twice for in the same context is not necessary just create a variable.

```
var dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("DROPDOWN"));
if (dropdown.Displayed()) 
{
    var selectElement = new SelectElement(dropdown);
    selectElement.SelectByValue("valuehere");
}
```

If you are using the text rather than the value in the select box you can use SelectByText("texthere"); instead of SelectByValue.

Comment: Thanks. The solution in the link is the same as above using a try catch. I'll try rewriting using something other than xpath but the code is all created with  Angular and we've had challenges locating elements.

Comment: If just create your own ElementIsVisible function like in the example you can call that rather than putting try catch all over the place

Answer (score 1):

isDisplayed() will work if the element is present in the DOM, followed by the style attribute :- display should not be false or none.

If prior action is a selection which led both the element to be displayed, it means the element is in the DOM but that wont be visible. So checking the visibility condition would return u false.

Try waiting for the element to get visible and perform the check operation on it which would reduce the sync latency.

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver(),5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated("By Locator"));

```
if (dropdown.isDisplayed())
```

````````````
   `````````// If the dropdown is tagged with <Select> tag
   ``````````` Select dropDown = new Select(dropdown);
    ```````````dropDown .selectByValue("value);

  ```````` // Else fetch the dropdown list item and store it in a list and iterate through and perform the desired action
    ```````````List<WebElement> dropDownList = new ArrayList<Webelements>;
    ```````````dropDownList.forEach(element -> {
        ```````````if(element.getText().equals("value")){
           ``````` ````element.click();
       ``````````` }
   ``````````` });

    ```````````driver.findElement(By.id("CheckBox")).click(); 
}
````````````

Comment: In some cases the element will not become visible. With the first selection, depending on what's selected, other options are available.

Comment: So, for that, if actions are likely, first selection(Option1) will populate some dropdown(Option1-dd) and Second selection(Option2) will populate some dropdown(Option2-dd)...make a generic private method with parameter(WebElement dropdown, String value), and call the private generic method from individual method with defined dropdown locator as input to the method.